# Apply sort on sum of child object's property MongoDB .net core

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to apply sort on sum of child object's property, below are three classes Instance, Template, and Sample. Template have list of Samples and I want to apply sort on sum of "SampleData" property of Samples.

```
public class Instance
{
    public long IId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long TemplateId { get; set; }
    public Template Template { get; set; }
}

public class Template
{
    public long TId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public List<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
}

public class Sample
{
    public long SId { get; set; }
    public long TemplateId { get; set; }
    public long SampleData { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

I use below code but getting error,

```
var data = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Instance>("Instance").Aggregate()
    .Lookup("Templates", "TemplateId", "TId", @as: "Template")
    .Lookup("Sample", "TemplateId", "TemplateId", @as: "Template.Samples")
    .Unwind("Template")
    .Unwind("Template.Samples")
    .As<Instance>()
    .SortByDescending(x=>x.Template.Samples.Sum(x=>x.SampleData))
    .ToList();
```

Getting below error,

```
Unable to determine the serialization information for x => Convert(x=>x.Template.Samples.Sum(x=>x.SampleData), Object).
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I think you need a grouping  with the sum. Then sort the grouped values.

Comment: Is grouping affect the performance of the query?

Comment: use raw string form instead expression in the same way as you did with unwind and lookup